# Question related to minimizing numerical errors

Tags: python, sum

I'm currently learning python, and going through a python introduction book.
In one of the questions, you should predict the most accurate result when summating a series of floating point numbers:

A) 0.01 + 0.02 + 0.03 +...+ 0.99 + 1.00

B) 1.00 + 0.99 + 0.98 +...+ 0,02 + 0.01

The book says the the method in A) will produce the most accurate result because the two numbers to be added will about the same size.

I don't understand why adding two numbers with a very different size will give a more inaccurate result compared to adding two numbers with the exact same size. Can anybody please help me understand this? Thanks in advance.

I've added a screenshot of the question directly from the book:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y2n5.png)

Comment: First, the claim seems valid for the given range. By a margin of `1e-13 %`. I think that's more attributable to floating point errors of an intermediate result. But, I can't find (by randomly testing ranges) another range where this also holds true. For the range `0.01, ..., 0.09` the first arrangement is less accurate.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.